# Installing laravel and homestead on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, ssh, virtualbox, putty

For the past few days I have been having a few problems trying to install laravel. I've finally made some bit of progress today when I figured out that I need to have vt-x enabled but I'm still having some problems.

I imagine these are easy to fix but I'm a bit lost.

I'm using the latest versions of composer, laravel and homestead.

I have all 3 installed. I have created a test folder on my local machine C:\www\laravel_projects

In here I have a laravel project just called tests.

In my user directory c:\users\user_name\ I have my .homestead file. Here is my homestead.yaml file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/ssh/key.ppk

keys:
    - ~/ssh/key

folders:
    - map: C:/www/laravel_projects/test
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: example.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
```

After a bit of messing around I finally managed to get homestead up and running and ssh'd into it. However I can't find any trace of my tests project on the machine.

So my first question is does anyone have any suggestions as to where I've gone wrong?

And my second is to do with ssh keys. I'm fairly new to these so please bear with me. I using puttygen I created a private and public key which I put in a folder called ssh in my user directory. In the homestead.yaml you can see that I pointed it to the locations. When I tried to ssh into homestead it was refusing my ssh key. After a while I noticed in homestead the line:

C:/Users/user_name/.homestead/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key

Once I pointed putty to that it worked. Can someone explain to me why I wasn't able to use the ssh keys I generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Problem: Not being able to see the test projects**

What was wrong is your folder mapping, specifically this part of your homestead.yaml file

```
folders:
- map: C:/www/laravel_projects/test
  to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
- map: example.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

I have a hunch it should read:

```
folders:
- map: C:/www/laravel_projects
  to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
- map: example.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public
```

=======================================

**Second Problem: SSH keys**

I recommend you get yourself gitbash and save yourself alot of headaches with this not only for that issue but you'll get some really weird output if you use cmd prompt because color codes are enabled and windows doesnt use them.

Comment: Yep think I got it going. I'm using CMDER for command line now and you're correct about the paths in my homestead file. Thanks for the help!